# Adding a column of code on right in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, ergonomics

How can I add the picture of all my code minified on right of my code view in Visual Studio?

Here is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Langagues -> Scroll Bars`, and select `Use Map Mode for vertical scroll bar`.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2014/03/using-the-map-mode-scroll-bar.aspx